# How can I get current user roles for specific document in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, roles

I can add a role to a document with this code:

```
var REST = globalvars.absoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Sharing.DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo";

var data = JSON.stringify({
    'resourceAddress': fileAdress,
    'userRoleAssignments':
        [{
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Sharing.UserRoleAssignment' },
            'Role': role,
            'UserId': sharedWith
        }],
    'validateExistingPermissions': false,
    'additiveMode': true,
    'sendServerManagedNotification': sendEmail,
    'customMessage': contentEmail,
    'includeAnonymousLinksInNotification': false
});
```

But I don't know how to retrieve this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to **get user effective permissions** as the following

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + Library Title + "')/getusereffectivepermissions(@user)?@user='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'"
```

Also, check

- [Lists and list items REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433(v=office.15).aspx)
- [GetUserEffectivePermissions(loginName) REST call on a list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/123864cc-eb81-4203-a4d4-2b3f82536019/getusereffectivepermissionsloginname-rest-call-on-a-list?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: Thank you. I found query to specific list item on your link.   url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /lists(guid'a290086b-2d43-4151-add4-893474a930a9')/items(2)
    /getusereffectivepermissions(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%40domain.onmicrosoft.com'
    &@target='<host web url>'",